# Why does the transformation bring bad results?

Tags: polygon, wms, vector, openlayers, coordinate-system

I have this map which has a polygon drawn on it. For the background map I use a WMS via `ol.source.TileWMS` and the polygon uses a `ol.source.Vector` object. Normally my view projection is `EPSG:31467` but now I tried to load another WMS which does not know  `EPSG:31456` but `EPSG:25832` instead.

I know up to day OL3 cannot reproject raster data, so I decided to automatically create a new view-obj when the new WMS (more precisely the layer) becomes visible. The new view has the transformed (from 31467 to 26832) center of the old view. As the polygon is in the wrong place now, I transform its geometry as well. Eventually I experienced the problem that the view’s center and the polygon seem to be translated by about 40m.

Why is that? I do not care for the visual difference between the different center positions, but the polygon is in the wrong position now. It is in the same position on screen but not on the map. I thought it should work when I create a new view, and I do not expect the transform function to make such a big difference.